# How to export -verbose results for multiple files from ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, rgb

I successfully used -verbose to find median RGB values for 1 .jpg file.

Next step is finding median RGB values for about 2000 .jpg files.

Id like to figure out how to do this automatically rather than one at a time.

Id also like to figure out how to export the data resulting from -verbose over 2000 files to something like .csv or .txt.

Does anyone know how to best approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you all details of all .jpg images in the current working directory:

```
identify -verbose *.jpg >verbose.txt
```

If you are on a Unix system, this one will dump to verbose.txt lines with `filename => overall RGB mean value`:

```
for f in *.jpg; do echo "$f => `identify -verbose "$f" | grep mean | tail -n1 | cut -d':' -f2 | xargs`"; done >verbose.txt
```

This one will dump to verbose.txt lines with `filename => R = mean value, G = mean value, B = mean value`:

```
for f in *.jpg; do echo "$f => `identify -verbose "$f" | grep mean | head -n3 | cut -d':' -f2 | xargs | awk '{print "R = "$1" "$2", G = "$3" "$4", B = "$5" "$6}'`"; done >verbose.txt
```

Comment: Actually just one clarification if its not too much to ask. How can I generate median red, median green, and median blue values for each image? If there are clues somewhere in the documentation that Im not seeing that would be helpful as well.

Comment: I've updated my answer with one more example which seems to achieve your desired output. :)